# run asp.net on apache

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono

I want to run an ASP.NET site on Apache Server instead of IIS.

I've Googled a lot, but didn't find satisfactory answers. I only found out that we can use something called 'Mono' - a third party API for doing this. Can anyone explain the basics - for example, do we need to install install .NET on that server? What if it is a UNIX server?

Any detailed explanation, or links, if provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is exactly what you're looking for, actually.  It's an extremely mature and stable product that's been providing .NET Framework support on open systems for a very long time.  [mod_mono](http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono) for Apache is specifically what you need.

To answer your questions:

- The .NET Framework itself won't install on non-Windows machines.  Mono is its replacement.  So you don't need to install the .NET Framework from Microsoft.
- Unix, Linux, etc.  Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm using mod_mono to run a couple of .net2.0 websites and it works perfectly, I haven't got around to testing any higher framework versions yet but it should be compatible with all of 3.5 and most of 4.0

Comment: @Fishcake: Early in the project they had a hard time keeping up with the changes from 1.1 to 2.0, but these days it's pretty advanced and seems to be innovating more than Microsoft with what .NET can do.  MonoTouch is a great example of some fantastic parts of the overall project.

Answer (score -1):

Mono is an open-source version of the .Net Framework and can be integrated into Apache as described here:

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

I believe this is your only option.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tutorial about mod_mono + apache configuration:

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono

AFAIK mod_mono + Apache is only working with a linux machine, not a windows machine.
It is not possible to install .net framework on linux.