# asp.net page display only html tags in localhost?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

asp.net page display only html tags When I want to show in my localhost. I have created a asp.net website project in vs 2010. And move the Published files to C:\wamp\www\CRS for localhost. But asp.net page display only html tags. see the Image.

This is a website project not web application. So I can't Build the package and Import to IIS. Pls help me.

[image]

Edit 1-

When I move All files to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\crs and access in localhost,.. It gives Configuration Error.

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

What I miss?

Comment: Deploy that site on IIS using VS2010 Publish web site option. That should work.

Comment: @Nilesh I have right click the project in solution explorer and runed  Publish Web Site. Is any other Deploy method is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use IIS to run ASP.net.

It seems you are using Apache. If you REALLY want to use Apache you need to install mono : [run asp.net on apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106593/run-asp-net-on-apache)

Otherwise setup a new website in IIS and point to your directory.

Comment: I have Installed IIS and Apache. So how can I run my website in ASP.net. Am I want to move the files to innetpub?

Answer (score 0):

as @basarat give a way to solve this question.

1) Copy and paste the Published website files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

2) In IIS right Cilck the Default website and Add Application property. It opens the Add Application window.

3) Give the name in Alias Field, then Give a Correct path of project.

[image]

4) Then you can access the asp.net page in localhost

Answer (score -1):

check the content type that the page is served with it has to be "text/html" instead of what you have