# Are the .config files part of ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono

I'm programming a web with the MVC pattern, so I've created the Web.config files that I needed (~/Web.config and ~/Views/Web.config), but I want run my web in Apache.
I've heard .config files only run in IIS. What can I do?
What multiplatform solution I need?

Example of Web.config

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Myweb" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106593/run-asp-net-on-apache.

Comment: With "If you use AddHandler you might want to let mod-mono-server know about your DirectoryIndex directive by doing something like this in your web.config file:" should I understand I needn't change my Web.config files. All right (just add some thing)?

Comment: I have exactly zero experience running ASP.Net on Apache, but from a quick read of http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/ it looks like you can ignore that comment for now. I'd suggest getting mono installed and try to configure your solution to work with it. If you run into further problems, you can ask more specific questions, although they will perhaps be better suited to another stack exchange site (webmasters maybe?).